# Website is not loading web.xml on hosting

Tags: java

I have been trying to deploy my website for over a week now first i'll explain the website then the problem then what i've tried:

The website is a simple form to enlist yourself into a course. the url is www.inschrijventypecursus.nl if you go onto it it does work, you can see the website now the problem:

I am trying to make calls to a HTTPServlet java controller. Now that does not work because my web.xml is not loaded in. I can see that because I edited the web.xml to this:

Can anyone help me find a anwser? I cannot find this problem anywhere without the things i tried myself. I even disabled mod_security via htaccess

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <display-name>AjaxJSP</display-name>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>CourseController</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>houseoftyping.controller.CourseController</servlet-class>

    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>CourseController</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>FormController</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>houseoftyping.controller.FormController</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>FormController</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/FormController</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

I also tried removing my servlet mapping from web.xml and adding it to the java classes

CourseController:

```
@WebServlet("/CourseController")
public class CourseController extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#HttpServlet()
     */
    public CourseController() {
        super();
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse
     *      response)
     */
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        response.setContentType("text/plain");
        String code = request.getParameter("code").toUpperCase();
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
        Course course = new Course(code);
        if(course.isFound()) {
            out.print(course.toString());
        } else {
            out.print(false);
        }
    }

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse
     *      response)
     */
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        doGet(request, response);
    }

}
```

This is my Ajax call:

```
$("#courseForm").submit(function() {
   var code = "";
   $('.code').each(function() {
       code = code + $(this).val();
   });
   if (code.length == 9) {
       $.ajax({
           type : 'POST',
           data : {
               code : code
           },
           url : 'CourseController',
           success : function(result) {
               if(result=="false") {
                   $("#wrongCode").css("display", "block");
                   $("#codeSection").css("display", "none");
               } else {
                   var course = result.split(":");
                   $("#schoolName").text(course[0]);
                   console.log(course[3]);
                   $("#courseCode").val(course[3]);
                   console.log($("#courseCode").val());
                   resetPrice(course[1], course[2]);
                   $("#codeSection").css("display", "none");
                   $("#registrationForm").css("display", "block");
               }
           }
       });
   }
   return false;
});
```

And my folder structure:

```
Root Folder
    src
        main
            java
                houseoftyping
                    controller
                        CourseController.java
                        FormController.java
                    (*other java packages with classes*)
            resources
                    (*properties files for other java classes*)
    META-INF
    resources
        js
            form.js
    WEB-INF
        lib
        web.xml
    index.html
```

Comment: This there an error message returned to the client or logged on the server log?

Comment: @David for the client it returns a 404 not found message. I do not know what it returns in the server log

Comment: @David in the serverlog it says this: [Mon Jun 15 12:05:06 2020] [error] [client 111.69.93.189] File does not exist: /var/www/vhosts/91/353695/webspace/httpdocs/inschrijventypecursus.nl/CourseController, referer: http://www.inschrijventypecursus.nl/?

Comment: I think you are not actually calling the url correctly. The context is missing from the URL do you know what that is? It is the name in tomcat of the deployed app

Comment: @David no, how can i add the context to the url?

Comment: Are you using tomcat?

Comment: On the hosting? I have no clue what is used on the hosting. I am hosting my website on a other host: www.hostnet.nl

Comment: I'm not sure if that is a Tomcat webapps directory it looks more like apache httpd. Is there a Tomcat server or another application server you can deploy the webapp or .WAR to?

Comment: No not really. It works on localhost that is a Tomcat localhost server. Are you hinting that i should deploy my webserver on a tomcat server?

Comment: yes you will need to deploy to a Java application server such as tomcat. If you have deployed to tomcat locally you will need to do the same when live. Typically a webhost is just a web server that will serve static html you will need to look for specific hosting of java code.

Comment: Unless there is a specific reason to use java I would maybe recommend PHP as this is generally widely offered and much more integrated with standard web hosting platforms. If you must use java (which is a fine choice) look for a Java host which is fairly easy to find or better yet host in a cloud platform which you configure such as Google cloud or AWS. Or alternatively use vps offering like linode etc

Answer (score 0):

Check your CORS settings.
If it's SSL, check your keystore if you'r using a selfsigned certificate.
Check your JS console in the browser, it will tell you what the base problem is.
Do you see logging for your servlet?